# Run Eclipse on RP4

Tags: java, raspberry-pi-os

Got Raspberry Pi 4 with 8Gb of RAM and would like to run Eclipse for it. But Eclipse does not provide 32 bit versions. Can I somehow get running latest version of Eclipse? What latest version I can download and use with my Raspberry Pi 4?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse for Linux is normally available either directly from them (x86 chipset only) or provided in the repository from the RPF.

I would make **at least** one back of your system then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y full-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot

sudo apt install eclipse
```

Notes:

- The autoremove may not be needed
- This can take a long while depending on your internet connection / speed of Pi (300Mb + was the package size)

Once loaded, it will be available under the 'Programming' menu in the Pi GUI